# R: check if a number is divisible by 5

Tags: r

I have a calculation in a for loop that I only want to execute when i is in 5,10,15,... (i.e. it is in the 5 times table).

How do I check in R if a number **i** is divisible by 5?

Comment: you can try `i %% 5 == 0`

Comment: To clarify, the `%%` operator is called the modulo, which is the remainder of a division. For example, the modulo 15 of 5 is zero, because there is no remainder. However, the modulo 16 of 5 is 1, and as such `16 %% 5 = 1`. That is why you can use it to check if a number is divisible by another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see an example:

```r
for (i in 1:10) { 
  if (i%%5 == 0) {
    print(paste0(i, "is divisible by 5"))}
  else {
    print(paste0(i, "is not divisible by 5"))}
}
#> [1] "1is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "2is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "3is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "4is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "5is divisible by 5"
#> [1] "6is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "7is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "8is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "9is not divisible by 5"
#> [1] "10is divisible by 5"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>